# Xcode Simulator 14.0 not deleting/ removing app

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I have recently updated 14.0 version of Xcode and simulator. I am facing a strange issue that app is not removing from the simulator. Before this update it's working perfect but after updated its showing this behaviour. Have a look a below, I have tried with both **Remove app** and **Edit Home screen** option. Both of them did't work for me. I have also tried to delete app from App library it also did't work.

[image]

Comment: It looks hosed. Delete the simulator itself and start over.

Comment: I tried what you recommend but same issue. @matt

Comment: Well, if you truly deleted the simulator, the app would _definitely_ be gone, so at least you have a workaround. — Unfortunately I can't reproduce this with Xcode 14.1. I always get the (annoying) usual three-step deletion dance, and the app deletes. I suggest filing a bug with Apple.

Answer (score 6):

I have figured out a workaround for this issue.

- If you can't uninstall the app you simply restart the simulator from the menu.
- Then try to uninstall the application with the usual way and it will work like a charm.

[restart menu screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThT4c.png)

Comment: This seems to still work in Xcode 15.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

So, I just ran into this weird issue as well, but I found that it wasn't consistent. Sometimes I could actually delete the app and sometimes I couldn't.

I think I figured out how to delete it every time:

- When the app is running, go into Xcode and press "Stop" (`CMD` + `.`)
- Now delete the app from the simulator

It's a work-around, but it doesn't look like Apple wants to fix this issue or maybe it was never reported to them, I don't know, but this seems to be working for me at least.

I'm running macOS Ventura 13.1, Xcode 14.2 and an iPhone 14 (iOS 16.2) simulator, so basically the newest versions and it's still present.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.